# Convert curl command to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I have this command

```
curl -k '"url."' -d 'APACScommand=NewRequest' -d 'data="XML"
```

I want to use the `curl` library of PHP.

I guess for `-k` flag I just call

```
curl_init($url)
```

I know that `-d` stands for *data*. Should I use something like this?

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

I see there are **two** *data* flag, isn't the second one going to override the first?

#### Edit

I've seen that `-k` flag may be replaced by

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

is it correct?Or it isn't even necessary to add it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this, use `http_build_query`

```
 $data = array('APACScommand'=>'NewPayment',
          'data'=>$command
          );

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$reply=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is `-k` flag?

Comment: It return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.

Comment: I did exactly what you told me and it work but then I tried it later and I had a problem with the second data which is XML, can you help me out?

Comment: what is your data to be passed ?

Comment: I updated my post I hope you see what the problem is?

Comment: can you change your structure as like mine

Comment: I don't see the difference,your change is identical to mine.

Comment: http_build_query(data) should be like  http_build_query($data)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41602/discussion-between-yannis-hristofakis-and-chinnu-r)

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/xml'));

Answer (score 1):

Just build the data as an array:

```
$data = array('APACScommand' => 'NewRequest', 
              'data' => 'XML');
```

And then simply pass this:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Comment: cURL can accept an array directly and do the query-building itself. So `http_build_query()` isn't required.